# Paypal NVP and classic asp

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

i have used the paypal nvp (name value pair) in sandbox. all worked. when the client approved to go live. i have changed the url, username, password... all seems fine.

but...

adding to cart on the site and sending to paypal with server side MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP with method "SetExpressCheckou" work. i get the token. than getting back from paypal and executing "GetExpressCheckoutDetails" works. on same page load i then need to execute "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" but i get "opetation time out "

i have tried "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" and tried setting timeout for the process or for the page or for the website in the IIS - nothing work stable as it should!

```
    Set paypalHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    paypalHTTP.Open "POST", requestURL, False


    paypalHTTP.Send requestPARMS
    paypalHTTP.waitForResponse 5
```

what can be done here?

Comment: I do not know about NVP. But, all I can say is, `waitForResponse` requires an asynchronous request to work, otherwise ignored. So if you really want to wait 5 seconds you have to set `paypalHTTP.Open`'s third parameter  to `True` instead of `False`.

Comment: I tried what you said and i got another error. tried everything. went back to sandbox and all is good :/